# How many ways to distribute 25 similar balls over 5 boxes such that no box is empty?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many ways to distribute 25 similar balls over 5 boxes such that no box is empty?

My turn:

The total number of ways is
$$C^{25 +5 -1}_{5}$$
Now I want to calculate the number of ways such that one box is empty to subtract them from the total to get the required, but I do not know how I can do it?

Comment: If you subtract the cases in which a ball is empty, you would need to use the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  It is easier to put a ball in each box, then distribute the remaining balls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the number of ways in which you can fill 5 identical boxes with 25 identical balls when none of them are empty will be $25-5+5-1\choose 5-1$ or ${24\choose 4} = 10626$.

If you want to use inclusion-exclusion principle, Total ways to fill boxes $={25+5-1\choose 5-1}={25\choose 4}=23751$

Ways in which 1 box is empty and rest are filled $={5\choose 1}\times {24\choose 3}=10120$

Ways in which 2 boxes are empty and rest are filled $={5\choose 2}\times {24\choose 2}=2760$

Ways in which 3 boxes are empty and rest are filled $={5\choose 3}\times {24\choose 1}=240$

Ways in which 4 boxes are empty and rest are filled $={5\choose 4}\times {24\choose 0}=5$

Total Number of Ways to fill boxes $=23751-10120-2760-240-5=10626$

Answer (score 1):

There are $5$ boxes.  Put a ball in each.  So all that remains to calculate is how to place the $20$ remaining balls in the $5$ boxes.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Since all $25$ balls are indistinguishable, we can put a ball in each box. There are $20$ remaining balls and $5$ boxes.

From here, you calculate using "stars and bars" $$\binom{24}{4}=\frac{24\cdot 23\cdot 22\cdot 21}{4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}=10626$$
$\boxed{10626}$ is your final answer.

Comment: What does "star and bars" mean ?@Taiga Agiat

Comment: @HussienMohamed Stars and bars is a method of counting how many ways to distribute indistinguishable balls into distinguishable boxes.

More on here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)